# How to tell if a Linux machine supports io_uring?

Tags: linux

I would like to check whether a Linux machine supports io_uring. How can this be done?

Is there some kernel file that describes support for this, or do all Linux 5.1+ kernels have support?

Comment: NB: it seems that some version of io_uring [was/is backported to RHEL >= 8.3/8.4](https://twitter.com/axboe/status/1288903631077552133) which ships with a (patched) 4.18 kernel.

Comment: @maxschlepzig No io_uring has been backported to RHEL 8 yet (see https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1769597#c19 and https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1881561 ). Jens' tweet was based on a misinterpretation of the release note talking about how it had been added to `libseccomp` not the kernel...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`io_uring` doesn’t expose any user-visible features, *e.g.* as a `sysctl`; it only exposes new system calls. It is available since kernel 5.1, but support for it can be compiled out, and it might be backported to older kernels in some systems.

The safest way to check for support is therefore to [check whether the `io_uring` system calls are available](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/164704/86440). If you have `/proc/kallsyms`, you can look there:

```
grep io_uring_setup /proc/kallsyms
```

Another way to check for the system call is to attempt a safe but malformed call, and check whether the resulting error is `ENOSYS`, for example:

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <linux/io_uring.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  if (syscall(__NR_io_uring_register, 0, IORING_UNREGISTER_BUFFERS, NULL, 0) && errno == ENOSYS) {
    // No io_uring
  } else {
    // io_uring
  }
}
```

On a kernel supporting `io_uring`, the available operations vary as new features are introduced with new kernel versions; to determine the supported operations, [use `io_uring_get_probe`](https://github.com/shuveb/loti-examples/blob/master/probe.c).

Answer (score 6):

It's available from Linux 5.1 and upwards and can be enabled during compiling. In Debian and derivatives you can locate the kernel options used during compilation in file `/boot/config-{kernel version}-{arch}`. In UEFI machines this path may be different.

So type,
`grep -i uring /boot/config-$(uname -r)`

The output should include `CONFIG_IO_URING`, y or n, enable or not.